# Bar series plotting for status

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I have a requirement where I should plot a bar chart as shown below. [image]

In the below image each color represents different status. I have a data structure where 'machine off' status will be on from time 1 to till time 2. I should plot a bar series only in that status is on. How I can achieve this using a bar series in wpf toolkit.

Early help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone looking a solution for this .

I have achieved this using a custom panel (Gantt Panel). I referred [this](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/09/how-to-create-gantt-control-in-wpf.html) blog. I did some modification based on my need.